# Remove unused references in VBA

Tags: vba

We are using an application (TeleForm) that uses VBA scripting.

We recently moved to a new server, when the moved happened, there are some VBA referenced libraries that still point to the old server.

How can I removed unused references that have a path to the old server?? Or update the path to the new location??

[image]

Example... The Test reference is located on the old server. If I attempt to uncheck this reference, browse to the new reference on the new server, when OK is clicked & I go back into the references, the old reference is rechecked & new reference is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps.

1. Remove the broken references, OK the dialog.
2. Bring up the dialog again; add the correct references, OK.

Comment: When you say 'remove' do you mean uncheck, click OK, then add the correct??  I have done that, but being the old & new have the same name, the old reference is always rechecked.

Comment: Hmm try removing, saving, exiting the host application completely, then reopening and re-adding the references. If that's still pointing to the old locations, something is wrong with the embedded VBA project.